# Unable to delete a "user" from Azure B2C AD using "Issuer Assigned id"

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to migrate users to Azure B2C Active Directory.

Earlier I was creating "users" that I was reading from a JSON file and creating them, however if any "user" in the JSON was already present in Azure B2C AD, I was getting an exception...

```
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: Request_BadRequest
Error message: Another object with the same value for property userPrincipalName already exists.
```

I was handling all those "users" with a simple try/catch and skipping them and moving them to next user in the JSON.

Now I need to delete the existing user in the process (Once I get above exception, I will delete the user)

I tried this...

```
    private void deleteExistingUser(String issuerAssignedId, IGraphServiceClient graphClient) {
        graphClient.users(issuerAssignedId).buildRequest().delete();
        LOG.info("User deleted.");
    }
```

But when above code is hit I am getting below exception...

```
Error message: Resource 'shumi' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

I believe this is happening because I am using userPrincipalName (issuerAssignedId) to delete the user,
Instead I should be using "azure retured user id to delete the user.

Is there a way I can get azure retured user id or some other way to delete the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, if you already knew the `userPrincipalName`, no need to get the user id i.e. object id manually, just delete the user via the filter with `userPrincipalName` directly.

Use something like below, `xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com` is the `userPrincipalName`.

```
graphClient.users().buildRequest()
.filter("userPrincipalName eq 'xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'")
.delete();
```

Comment: I did something similar, instead I created one QueryOption and used UserCollectionPage, your approach is smaller and looks better.